# Maven MultiModule Project Is Not Reading Configuration/Properties Files When Run From Terminal

Tags: java, maven, configuration, properties-file, multi-module

I have a maven project with two modules a client and a server. Each module needs to read some properties from a configuration file. When build/run from inside IntelliJ IDE it works just fine. However when i use mvn package and run client and server from the terminal, when changing properties values inside the relative configuration files that are located inside the corresponding target/classes directories nothing happens. They both continue to have the initial/old values and not the new/updated ones.

The project structure is the following:

```
Project
--Client
  --src
    --main
      --java
        Client JavaCode Files
      --resources
        client.conf
  pom.xml
--Server
  --src
    --main
      --java
      Server JavaCode Files
      --resources
        server.conf
  pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Each module has a separate configuration file inside its corresponding resources directory. 
The main/father project pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0           http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
<artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>Server</module>
    <module>Client</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- any other plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The client module pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
    <groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
<artifactId>Client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/main/resources/client.config</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The Server pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
        <groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
    <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/main/resources/server.config</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please Help... What am i doing wrong?? I am sure there must be something completely obvious which i can't see...

Comment: Not know if it solves your problem, but there is one simple rule: Never ever change files in `target` folder manually.

Comment: But target directory it the compiler output. Everything that is build is put there. So if i want to move my compiled project to another machine i use the files of the target folder right?? If i want to change configuration before run how do i do it??

Comment: Then you move it into any other folder outside `target`, because every next compilation overwrites `target` folder with resources from `src/main`. Some IDEs does this compilation on the fly sometimes.

Comment: First defining maven-assembly-plugin in the parent of the project will not work, cause the parent will run at first. Furthermore to read property files/configuration files from outside you need to do that correctly inside your application and do not use properties-maven-plugin cause it's intended for Maven build itself (build-time) and not run time...You should read your configuration file based on user home directory etc.